# Dynamically changing class name based on window size

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to create a responsive site using the following layout (simplified for this question):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <!-- Left menu -->
        <div class="span2">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                MENU CONTENT GOES HERE
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="mainContent" class="span7">
            MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE
        </div>

        <!-- Right column -->
        <div id="rightColumn" class="span3 hidden-phone hidden-tablet">
            RIGHT COLUMN GOES HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the browser window resizes to tablet size, the rightColumn div is hidden as expected - but it leaves white space next to the mainContent div (with a size of span3).

I would like the mainContent div to expand to full width (so it fills out matches span10 in size).

I am using the following jQuery code to dynamically change the class name for the mainContent div to achive this (and it works as expected):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = $(window);

        // Function to handle changes to style classes based on window width
        function checkWidth() {
        if ($window.width() < 980) {
            $('#mainContent').removeClass('span7').addClass('span10');
            };

        if ($window.width() >= 980) {
            $('#mainContent').removeClass('span10').addClass('span7');
        }
    }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();

    // Bind event listener
        $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

My question: is this the preferred way to handle changes to spans in Twitter Bootstrap when the browser window resizes? Or should I just change the CSS for span7 for tablet screen sizes to match that of span10?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I will answer it myself: I removed the Javascript code and replaced it with this simple change to the Bootstrap CSS to change the width of span7 to the same width as span10 for tablet screen sizes:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .row-fluid .span7 {
    width: 82.87292817100001%;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is simple to change the CSS for individual setting, how about if difference between two are not so simple?

Answer (score 0):

but media queries don't work on ie8 and below. 
i think you're better off with the js fix. then again, ie8's not gonna hide the span3 anyway.

but here's what i use.
When you remove the class span7 from that div, it automagically takes up 100% of the remaining width, assuming you don't have styles that specifically set the width of #mainContent

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <!-- Left menu -->
        <div class="span2">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                MENU CONTENT GOES HERE
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="mainContent" class=""> <!-------------remove the span7---->
            MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE
        </div>

        <!-- Right column -->
        <div id="rightColumn" class="span3 hidden-phone hidden-tablet">
            RIGHT COLUMN GOES HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```