# Dropdown menu does not work after resizing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm starting with bootstrap and made a little html template with just a menu header (with dropdown items).

The problem is that after i resize the window to be small enough to force the responsive menu collapse, use the dropdown (navigate) while collapsed, and after that i maximize the window, the dropdown menu item stops working (shows a scroll to view content instead of dropping-down).

Sample code? Just try the "Navbar Template" from bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Is there any known fix for this problem?

Tested in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

add this after your Bootstrap's CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) 
{   
    .navbar-collapse.in{ overflow-y:visible;}
}
```

--end update

Yes, this look "strange" the "in" class have effect after re-sizing still.

You could remove the class with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var $window = $(window);

        // Function to handle changes to style classes based on window width
        function checkWidth() {

        if ($window.width() >= 768) {
            $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in').addClass('collapse');
        }
    }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();

    // Bind event listener
        $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Resize code from: [Dynamically changing class name based on window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917216/dynamically-changing-class-name-based-on-window-size), better solutions to do this: [How to detect responsive breakpoints of Twitter Bootstrap 3 using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575582/how-to-detect-responsive-breakpoints-of-twitter-bootstrap-3-using-javascript)

<strike>Maybe it is also possible to reset the .in class for screenwidth above the breakpoint with a media query.</strike>

It seems to be a bug, see: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11243

Answer (score 1):

The other answer didn't work for me, as the collapse class added a display:none; (perhaps a different version of Bootstrap). The solution that worked for me is adding to your responsive CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .collapse{ display:block;}
}
```

For me the issue occurred when I Open and then Close the collapsed menu, followed by a resize. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Forcing auto height on the collapsing element (above breaking point) worked for me.

Find the id or class on the toggle button eg. `data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"` and use min-width (your breaking point):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-ex1-collapse { height:auto !important;}
}
```